# Changing my primary email and thus Apple ID Fails. Can anyone help?

Tags: email, apple-id

My email provider and thus also email address are changing.  Thus I carefully followed the procedure Apple provide to change the primary email used for Apple ID.  I used the "Managing Apple ID" Web pages.  I had already, as instructed, signed out of and closed all services and devices using the existing Apple ID.

However when I click "edit" and enter the replacement email and click "continue" but nothing happens.  The progress circle continues turning and eventually the page times out.  I have tried many things over 2 days!

It appears to be stuck but why?  There is no verification code email delivered (even in "junk" etc) and no popup to receive a verification code anyway.

Have others encountered this frustration and if so how did you overcome it?

Comment: It appears to be a problem with Internet Explorer vn 11.  I gave up on the laptop and tried using my Apple iphone 6 using Safari  browser.  It worked immediately and it is celebration time.

Comment: Answer your own question then... It helps contribute to the site.

Comment: I HOPE MY EXPERIENCE IS OF USE TO OTHERS.

GOOD LUCK

Comment: er...okay But you can still answer your question formally.

Comment: Response to brick and in general.
The answer to my questions are as my second posting to this thread.
I repeat, there appears to be an incompatibility between the Apple "update ID" process and at least Internet Explorer - so a work round is to use Safari or another PC browser for the update. I have not explored further and thus have no further suggestions - others may know the detail but I regret I am unable to suggest more.
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my questions is that there appears to be an incompatibility between the Apple "update ID" process and at least Internet Explorer - so a work round is to use Safari or another PC browser for the update.

I have not explored further and thus have no further suggestions - others may know the detail but I regret I am unable to suggest more.